# Question from Halmos' Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is part of question 6 in the set of exercises following section 17 in Halmos' Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces.

*Suppose that $m < n$ and that $y_1,\dots,y_m$ are linear functionals on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. Under what conditions on the scalars $a_1,\dots,a_m$ is it true that there exists a vector $x$ in $V$ such that $[x, y_j] = y_j(x) = a_j$, for $j = 1,\dots,m$?*

The question at first looked like one that would admit a straightforward solution but I can't come up with one, perhaps I am missing something simple. At the moment all I have is that the $a_j$ must satisfy any linear dependence equation that the $y_j$ satisfy (by evaluation at $x$). The previous question was similar except that the $a_j$ were all $0$ (asking if there then exists a non-zero $x$) and that I answered by considering the elements of $V$ as those of its double dual and arguing that the annihilator of the span of the $y_j$ must have a non-zero dimension.

Comment: Hint: Write the scalar $a_j = a_j * 1$ in terms of some element of the dual basis applied to $x$ and then you can rearrange to land in the case of the previous question.

Comment: Sorry I meant dual space!

Comment: @fretty Thanks for the hint but I unfortunately still don't see it, $x$ is something we need to find rather than something given? I tried using $x$ as a solution to the homogeneous case given by the previous question but that disallows the rearrangement. I then thought that perhaps you meant suppose we found such a required $x$ then do as you say to find a necessary rather than sufficient condition on the $a_j$'s but then the $y_j$'s are obvious possible elements of the dual space. Finally I see that you've written $a_j = a_j * 1$ but I can't see what you're trying to tell me there

Comment: "At the moment all I have is that the $a_j$ must satisfy any linear dependence equation that the $y_j$ satisfy" <- That's it. When that condition is satisfied, there is an $x$ with $y_j(x) = a_j$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I felt pretty sure that that would be sufficient but didn't have any strong argument supporting it

Comment: $V$ is - as a finite-dimensional space - naturally isomorphic to its bidual. So you have $m$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space ($V^\ast$), and want a criterion when there is a linear map $f$ with $f(y_i) = a_i$. Does it sound more familiar in that situation?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh wow yes I see, that's great, enlightening, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose first that $y_1,\ldots,y_m$ are linearly independent.

Define $y_{m+1},\ldots,y_n$, so that $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ form a basis of the dual of $X$, and let
$x_1,\ldots,x_n$ a basis of $X$, such that $y_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Then you are looking for $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, such that the $x=c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n$ satisfies $y_j(x)=a_j$, $j=1,\ldots,m$. Equivalently
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n c_ky_j(x_k)=c_j=a_j, \quad j=1,\ldots,m.
$$ 
Thus you have infinitely many such $x$'s:
$$
x=\sum_{k=1}^m a_kx_k+\sum_{k=m+1}^n c_kx_k,
$$
where the $c_k$'s are arbitrary - The $x$'s form a $(n-m)$-dimensional coset.

If $y_1,\ldots, y_m$ are not, then assume that $y_1,\ldots,y_r$ are linearly independent and
$y_{r+1},\ldots,y_m$ are linear combinations of $y_1,\ldots,y_r$. Then $a_{r+1},\ldots,a_m$
are also written accordingly as linear combinations of the $a_1,\ldots,a_r$, while we can find as before $x\in X$, such that $y_j(x)=a_j$, $j=1,\ldots,r$ -The $x$'s form a $(n-r)$-dimensional coset.